# Switch/Break indenting in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, indentation

I have a really dumb question and not really important but it has been bugging me for quite some time: how do I indent "correctly" the "break;" inside a switch statement in PHP?
Like this:

```
case "foo":  
    do_whatever(TRUE);  
    break;
case "bar":
    ...
```

or like this?

```
case "foo":
    do_whatever(TRUE);
break;
case "bar":
   ...
```

As I have said, it is silly but I'd like to know from more experienced programmers so that I can stick with one style (the most common one) and don't get baffled everytime.
Thank you!

Comment: Whichever you prefer and find more easily recognizable as blocks.

Comment: The most common way is to indent the `break`, but it is entirely up to you. If you want to use a standard that has been defined by others, you might want to try the [PSR1 & PSR2 standards](http://phpmaster.com/psr-1-and-psr-2-to-be-approved-as-standards/) from the PHP-FIG.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That depends on which standard you're following. [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) [indents break](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#52-switch-case):

```
<?php
switch ($expr) {
    case 0:
        echo 'First case, with a break';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'Second case, which falls through';
        // no break
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        echo 'Third case, return instead of break';
        return;
    default:
        echo 'Default case';
        break;
}
```

I believe this style is more common than the other.

Comment: +1 for specific standard reference instead of just opinion (which this still is, though).

Comment: Thank you all! The problem was that I find both readable for their own advantages, one because it reminds me more of parentheses and the other because, as Adder said, break is a statement and I can find all the "cases" easily. So, seeing there are written rules I will let them decide... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Technically the `break;` is a statement like the `echo`, so it should be on the same level.

Also, omitting the `break;` is allowed, `case` and `break;` don't really form a pair, the `break;` may be omitted for special effect (fall through).